# How to work out if someone is older that 19 in Excel

Tags: excel, date

I have a little problem with Excel. I nead to make a function that checks if a person is older that 19.

I checked for a function online but it does not work the way it should.

First I have a date in a unusual format 14 10 2012 , I used `=SUBSTITUTE(J2, " ", ".")`
to get 14.10.2012

after that I use a formula

```
=IF(P2<DATE(DAY(NOW()),MONTH(NOW()),YEAR(NOW())),"Older than 
19","Too young")
```

but no mater what I do it does not work correctly. It shows the same resolute if the number is bigger or smaller

why is `=DATE(DAY(TODAY()),MONTH(TODAY()),YEAR(TODAY()))` showing me 3.4.1920 ?

Comment: Is the question about formatting your date? or about use of DATEDIF() to calculate age?

Comment: I'd go along along with Mark's DATEDIF suggestion, if you can convert your "date" to a valid format then you can use DATEDIF like `=IF(DATEDIF(A1,TODAY(),"Y")>=19,"Older","Younger")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=IF(YEAR(NOW())-RIGHT(J2,4)>55,"starejsi",IF(YEAR(NOW())-RIGHT(J2,4)=55,
IF(MONTH(NOW())-LEFT(RIGHT(J2,7),2)>0,"older",
IF(MONTH(NOW())-LEFT(RIGHT(J2,7),2)=0,
IF(DAY(NOW())-LEFT(J2,FIND(" ",J2,1))>=0,"older","younger"),"younger")),"younger"))
```

finally i have done it. this is the code

Comment: So "starejsi" = "older"? Try DATEDIF like `=IF(DATEDIF(SUBSTITUTE(J2," ","."),TODAY(),"y")>=55,"older","younger")` - I assume . is the required date separator for your region

Answer (score 1):

I think that you might have the parameters around the wrong way. If I put:

=DATE(DAY(TODAY()),MONTH(TODAY()),YEAR(TODAY()))

into Excel, I also get 3.4.1920.

If, however, I enter:

=DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),MONTH(TODAY()),DAY(TODAY()))

I get 14.10.2012 - today's date!

======

Just as a followup, I suspect that you are trying to compare today's date with a date of birth to determine someone's age and whether they are over 19?

Try this:

1. Enter the formula above into a cell (hidden if you like) - lets call it A1
2. Have the person's date of birth entered into another cell - lets say A2
3. Enter the formula =A1-A2 into a third cell (A3). This gives you their age in days.
4. Another formula - this time =A3/365.25 (that is, their age in days divided by the number of days in a year). Let's say that's A4
5. It's then a simple IF statement =IF(A4>19,"Over 19","Too young")

Hope that helps :-)

Comment: this works fine now :) thanks now i only nead to compare this to my date and still it shows true if the date is smaller or bigger

Comment: that should work perfectly. sadly if i use today and my date it makes an error. #value if i use 2x today it is fine but its 0 of course. if i use 2 my dates it is still #value

Comment: Can you explain exactly what you are trying to do and I'll see if I can help you. In Australian time zone, so getting close to bed time but if you get it to me quickly I may have an opportunity. If space doesn't permit, please me an email at xera@xera.com.au

Comment: the thing is that i have a date day month and year and i nead to know if the person is older than 19 years the problem is that someon didint use . or / to write the date but yust spaces

Comment: Ah, that's a bit more difficult. Not sure if I can help you with that one ... sorry.

Comment: thank you :) you helped me a lot . now i have finally done it